# How to make kCGPathStroke work in Swift 2?

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

I am getting two errors as I try to upgrade my app to Swift 2.

The two errors are:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'kCGPathStroke'

and:

> Cannot convert value of type 'NSMutableDictionary' to expected
>   argument type '[String : AnyObject]?'

Both issues are commented on in the code below. I checked the documentation and it looks like `kCGPathStroke` still exists, so I am really confused as to why this is broken. What am I doing wrong?

```
import UIKit
import CoreGraphics
class MIBadgeLabel: UILabel {
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect)
    {
        // Drawing code
        let ctx: CGContextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        let borderPath: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, byRoundingCorners:UIRectCorner.AllCorners, cornerRadii: CGSizeMake(10.0, 10.0))

        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor)
        CGContextSaveGState(ctx)
        CGContextAddPath(ctx, borderPath.CGPath)
        CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 4.0)
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, UIColor.clearColor().CGColor)
        CGContextDrawPath(ctx, kCGPathStroke) //Swift 2 error
        CGContextRestoreGState(ctx)

        CGContextSaveGState(ctx)
//      CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor)
        var textFrame: CGRect  = rect
        let labelString: NSString = self.text! as NSString
        let textSize: CGSize  = labelString.sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFontOfSize(13.0)])
        textFrame.size.height = textSize.height

        textFrame.origin.y = rect.origin.y + ceil((rect.size.height - textFrame.size.height) / 2.0)

        let paragraphStyle: NSMutableParagraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle();
        paragraphStyle.alignment = .Center

        var attributes: NSMutableDictionary = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(13.0), NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor(), NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paragraphStyle]

        labelString.drawInRect(textFrame, withAttributes: attributes)  // Swift 2 error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First error:

```
CGContextDrawPath(ctx, kCGPathStroke)
```

Like this:

```
CGContextDrawPath(ctx, .Stroke)
```

Second error:

```
var attributes: NSMutableDictionary = [
    NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(13.0), 
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor(), 
    NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paragraphStyle
]
```

Like this:

```
let attributes = [
    NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(13.0), 
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor(), 
    NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paragraphStyle
]
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve the identifier 'kCGPathStroke' issue, using Swift 2.0, use:

```
CGContextDrawPath(ctx, CGPathDrawingMode.Stroke)
```